# Model vs Input Validation for MVC 2 .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

MVC 2 comes with built-in support of Model validation but how do I do "input validation"? For example I have an interface of creating memo where I have populated the view with dynamic checkboxes corresponding to employees. The validation is straight forward i.e do not submit if no checkbox is selected.

I wonder if there is a way of doing such things in DataAnnotations. I have searched the internet and found that people have written a lot of code to validate password and confirm password validation just for the sake of doing it the nicer way.

My question is if there is a nicer way for my problem or should I just count number of checkboxes in my controller action and return error if no checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you looking at the [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) library which [integrates nicely with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/06/fluentvalidation-1-2-beta-2-and-mvc2-rc2/).

Comment: Thanks Darin,
could u plz refer some example or preferably a sample project to get started with FluentValidations

Comment: Take a look at the second link. It provides all that's necessary to get started. The documentation is also quite extensive.

Comment: Thanks Darin, i have tried using Fluent validation and it works great on server side but never shows up on client side using Microsoft validation. i searched about that and found that even xval provide limited support for fluent validation on client side. the rule i want to apply is 
RuleFor(x => x.Contact).EmailAddress().When(x => x.ContactType.Equals("Email"));
which works on server side
regards
Adeel

Comment: In the link I provided it states that for client validation: `at the moment, only the NotNull, NotEmpty, RegularExpression and Length validators are supported.`

Comment: Thanks Darin,
yes it does state that client side validation is supported for some trivial scenarios but what i want is to get complex validations on client side too. is there a way i can hook fluent validations json using jquery (preferably) or by some other js library. regards